# Plotting with a for loop in matplotlib, with lists

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
form_class = uic.loadUiType("GUI.ui")[0]  # Load the UI

class MainWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
  def __init__(self, target, Afb, np, conversion, parent=None):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    if self.RadioButton.isChecked():
        Ids, Ugs = unipolar_steuerkennlinie(self.target, self.Afb, self.np, self.conversion)

  def plot_matplotlibwidget(self, *args):
    for x in range(0, 40):
         self.matplotlibwidget.axes.plot([args[0][x]], [[args[1][x]]])
    self.matplotlibwidget.axes.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Hi, I have this function and I don't really know how to plot correctly. Now it shows nothing but the does change the scale.

Comment: Could you post a more complete example of your code so we can see what you are using as arguments to call ``plot_matplotlibwidget``?

Comment: `Ids, Ugs = unipolar_steuerkennlinie(self.target, self.Afb, self.np, self.conversion)
self.plot_matplotlibwidget(Ugs, Ids)`.

Comment: Ugs and Ids are lists

Comment: And what do the lists contain? Different x-vectors and y-vectors I assume?

Comment: In Ids are the  x-coordinate and in Ugs are the y-coordinate

Comment: To be honest, I am still confused what ``matplotlibwidget`` exactly is? Is this some mpl widget in a PyQt GUI? Moreover, why do you have ``[args[0][x]]`` instead of ``args[0][x]``. I generated a minimal example for myself with ``ax.plot(args[0][x], args[1][x])`` and it works.

Comment: Yes, matplotlibwidget is a widget in my GUI (PyQt4). I just tried the Version with `args[0][x]` and it doesn't work and sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example of your GUI (edit your question)? This would it make it easier to understand what is going on.

Comment: So I guess that ``matplotlibwidget`` gets initiated in ``setupUi``? What is the output if you do ``import numpy as np`` and then ``np.shape(args[0][x])`` and ``np.shape(args[1][x])`` right before the ``axes.plot`` call?

Comment: `[0.0, 0.10000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001, 0.30000000000000004, 0.40000000000000002, 0.5, 0.60000000000000009, 0.70000000000000007, 0.80000000000000004]` this is the x-axes and this is the y-axes `[0.06130492314696312, 0.058226246386766434, 0.04591154679656029, 0.09517034888267517, 0.055147573351860046, 0.03359684720635414, 0.09824901819229126, 0.14442914724349976, -0.024897973984479904, 0.15058650076389313]`

Comment: This is the first entry of ``args[0]`` and ``args[1]``, e.g.  ``args[0][0]`` and ``args[1][0]`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is hard to completely replicate your code and error, I've created you a simple minimal GUI that has a MPL widget and draws a few random lines.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import functools
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class test(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):

        self.widget=QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # Button to plot
        self.btnPlot = QtGui.QPushButton('Plot')
        self.btnPlot.connect(self.btnPlot, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.btnPlotPressed)

        # Line edit for number of lines
        self.qleN = QtGui.QLineEdit(str(0))

        # Create canvas
        self.setupMPLWidget()

        # Layout
        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.btnPlot)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.qleN)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)   


        self.show()

    def btnPlotPressed(self):

        """Plots a few lines."""

        # Get number of buttons to add
        n=int(self.qleN.text())

        # Generate some data
        xs,ys=self.randData(n)

        # Plot
        self.plot_matplotlibwidget(xs,ys)

    def randData(self,n):

        """Creates n random data sets."""

        ys=[]
        xs=[]
        for i in range(n):
            xs.append(np.arange(n-i))
            ys.append(np.random.random(size=xs[-1].shape))

        return xs,ys

    def plot_matplotlibwidget(self,*args):

        """Plots list of datasets."""

        for x in range(0, len(args[0])):
            self.ax.plot(args[0][x], args[1][x])
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()  

    def setupMPLWidget(self):

        """Sets up a MPL figure to draw on."""

        # Create parenting widget
        self.plotFrame = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.plotFrame.setMaximumWidth(1)

        # Create Figure
        self.fig = Figure( dpi=100)
        #self.fig.set_size_inches(100,100,forward=True)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.setParent(self.plotFrame)

        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)


def main():

    #Creating application   
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_win = test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It has a little QLE where you can specify how many lines you want to draw. I hope this helps.